# Best way to create a 3 state object in js

Tags: javascript

How do you create a 3 state object in javascript?
Let's say we want to make the game "Snake". There you have a grid of fields where the snake is able to move on. Every field is an object. The object should somehow have the properties "is it a field where the snake is on", "is it a field where a fruit is on" and "is it none of both". 
Should this be done with a string-property `({state: "fruit"/"snake"/"grass"})` or two boolean-properties `({isSnake: true/false, isFruit: true/false})`.

Which option should I use or is there a better option?

And a follow-up-question: Should I use getters and setters here or is this sufficient?

```
field.isSnake = true;
```

and in general, when should you use getters and setters?

Comment: In my opinion, they are just preferences of how you'd like to write your code. It also depends on the complexity of the class. From your description, I'd prefer the boolean properties since they are more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Try flag:

```js
const TypeFlags = {
  FRUIT: 1,
  SNAKE: 2,
  GRASS: 4,
};

const field = {
  flag: 1,
};

console.log(
  (field.flag & TypeFlags.FRUIT) !== 0, // fruit
  (field.flag & TypeFlags.SNAKE) !== 0, // snake
  (field.flag & TypeFlags.GRASS) !== 0 // grass
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Having two booleans, `isSnake` and `isFruit` is dangerous, as it can represent *four states*, but only three are valid. A snake can't be a fruit, but your code allows it to be one. Wether you take strings, numbers or Symbols to represent *three states* is personal preference.

Answer (score -2):

both of your answers depends upon programming Paradigms which you are following, learning Programming Paradigms in depth you will get your answers hopefully, 
as a beginner, I suppose you're using "Object-Oriented Programming" Paradigms then you should have to use Getter and setter, and yes flags like "isSanke" is more cleaning way  then using Strings